# How does Unity's QualitySettings.masterTextureLimit work?

Tags: unity, textures, graphics, sprites, mipmaps

I'm trying to get to the bottom of how [masterTextureLimit](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/QualitySettings-masterTextureLimit.html) works, but my results have been inconsistent so far.

I created a massive sprite (8192x8192), and I'd like to resize it at runtime to save performance. The idea is to start with large sprites and then resize based on the monitor's resolution. Here's what happens at different settings:

- Texture import size 8192, masterTextureLimit 0, mipmaps off: ~2ms
- Texture import size 8192, masterTextureLimit 0, mipmaps on: ~1.5ms
- Texture import size 8192, masterTextureLimit 1, mipmaps on: ~1.5ms
- Texture import size 4096, masterTextureLimit 0, mipmaps off: ~0.9ms
- Texture import size 4096, masterTextureLimit 0, mipmaps on: ~0.9ms
- Texture import size 4096, masterTextureLimit 1, mipmaps on: ~0.83ms

Looking at these results, I have a couple of questions:

- If masterTextureLimit is supposed to halve the texture resolution, why did it not affect performance while setting texture size to 4096 did?
- Why did turning mipmaps on improve performance at 8192 texture size but not at 4096? My camera is orthographic, and it's only 1 unit away from the sprite.

Comment: What are you using to resize the texture? Are you resizing it in a script and profiling how long the blit or resize operation takes? (Showing that code would help remove any ambiguity) Or are you scaling the GameObject it's being displayed on and measuring the render time for a frame?

Comment: I'm not resizing it manually — I'm just setting masterTextureLimit to 1 instead of 0, which the documentation says halves the texture size (unless I misinterpreted that). I'm using the Unity profiler and looking at how long the sprite takes to render, kind of like this: https://i.imgur.com/d0tKIun.png

Comment: Hmm... the mystery to me is why 4096-0-on performed faster than 8192-1-on - by my reading, those should result in the same texture & mip chain being used at runtime. :/  I'm missing something here...

Comment: It is pretty strange. I can always open a bug report with Unity, though in my experience there's a higher chance that I got confused somewhere along the line, heh.